# $T(n) = nT(n − 1), T(1) = 1$ for $n ≥ 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Hey I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this recurrence relation by repeated substitution? $T(n) = nT(n − 1), T(1) = 1$ for $n ≥ 1$ Thanks.

Comment: Have you worked out the first few values?

Comment: Instead of speaking of "solve" I would rather say that there is a well known notation for the solution: $n!$

Answer (score 0):

It's $n!$, by definition

$T(1)=1$

$T(2)=2\times 1$

$T(3)=3\times 2\times 1$

$...$

$T(n)=n(n-1)!$

Answer (score 0):

For $n\geq2$
$$T(n)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}T(k)=\prod_{k=1}^nT(k)=n\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}kT(k)=n!\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}T(k),$$
which gives $T(n)=n!.$